# android studio logcat drops date, process info

Tags: android-studio, logcat

After a recent Android Studio update (currently I'm running 3.1.2), logcat started intermittently dropping the time stamp and PID info.

```
05-01 13:26:03.962 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: SG(BI) Intercept DOWN, state NONE
    SG(BI) long timer started 1525206363962, for 500, to 1525206364462
05-01 13:26:03.965 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: SG(BI) DOWN, state ONE
05-01 13:26:04.008 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: SG(PF) Intercept UP, state ONE
    SG(PF) long timer cancelled
05-01 13:26:04.010 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: SG(BI) UP, state ONE
    SG(BI) long timer cancelled
    SG(BI) double timer started
05-01 13:26:04.011 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: SG(BI) UP, ret true
05-01 13:26:04.310 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: SG(BI) double timer done
    SG(BI) SINGLE_TAP 578,82
    BI single tap
    BL onNav
05-01 13:26:04.313 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: CF add: parent 7, child 23
    BTBP animateOpenChild: 1
05-01 13:26:04.338 12909-12909/com.perinote.perinote D/Perinote: IVH onDraw: tag 0, LOADED, IMG_20171007_181223.jpg
```

For example, on the 2nd line, you can see the same prefix SG(BI) but the preceding timestamp and process info is missing. Any ideas on why this is happening?

If I run logcat in a process window, this doesn't happen - all lines have the correct prefix info.

Comment: Totally annoying ! It's hard on the eyes not to have data line up. It means you can't filter the output, e.g. with grep. You can't tell if something is debug, error, warning, etc. Fix it, google !

Answer (score 4):

it's not intentional, bug has been fixed in 3.2

> This change in behavior was inadvertent and I reverted it. The fix
>   will go out in 3.2 [- issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77305804)

update android studio to 3.2 build 15 in the canary channel or wait for it to drop on the stable channel

Comment: Thanks ! Nice to know people are on top of the bugs.